# Is it possible to have sticky div inside an angular form?

Tags: html, css, forms, angular, sticky

I'm working with angular and angular-material.

Inside a page, I have a form, and some buttons (grouped in a div) which are depending on this form.

But, I'd like to have these buttons (the div) sticking the bottom of the page, even if I scroll.

Here's some code :

```
<form (ngSubmit)="update()" #updateForm="ngForm">
  <div> some content with inputs and selects </div>
  <div class="button-container"> buttons like save, cancel, ... </div>
</form>
```

and :

```
.button-container {
  position: sticky !important;
  bottom: 0;
  float: right;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

If I put the buttons out of the form, they don't work anymore. Thing is, it'd be better if I don't change the buttons' methods, and only modify HTML and CSS.
What I did doesn't work, any idea ?

I did this on plunker, with the same CSS properties as my project https://plnkr.co/edit/pw7zOruWwhV0o1Vya717?p=preview

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you have so far with something like [plunker](https://plnkr.co/)?

Comment: Plunker added !

Comment: Didn't you say you got it working on Plunker?

Comment: At first, I thought so. It's actuallys when using `<button>` that it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I updated the plunker with something closer to my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I had the same problem. Normally I would use position `fixed` but this wouldn't work because material used `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)`. This made `fixed` to behave like `absolute`. To solve this problem I used the below:

```
//Place this in your form

<app-fnls-displacer>
  <div style="position: fixed; right: 30px; bottom: 30px; padding-bottom: 2em; z-index: auto">
    <button mat-fab class="fab" type="submit" (click)="myfunction()">
      <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</app-fnls-displacer>
```

This is the component and directive used:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, Directive, OnDestroy, TemplateRef, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';

import {Overlay, OverlayRef, OverlayConfig, TemplatePortal} from '@angular/material';

@Directive({ selector: '[displacerPortal]' })
export class DisplacerPortalDirective extends TemplatePortal<any> {
  constructor(templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    super(templateRef, viewContainerRef);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fnls-displacer',
  template: `
    <ng-template displacerPortal>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </ng-template>
  `
})
export class DisplacerComponent implements OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

  private _config = new OverlayConfig();

  @ViewChild(DisplacerPortalDirective)
  private _portal: DisplacerPortalDirective;

  private _overlayRef: OverlayRef = undefined;

  constructor(private _overlay: Overlay) {}

  public ngOnDestroy() {
    this._overlayRef.detach();
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._overlayRef = this._overlay.create(this._config);
    this._overlayRef.attach(this._portal);
  }
}
```

I found it on a material GitHub page. It places the content inside it directly to the body, so that you can use `position: fixed`.

Comment: I can't find `OverlayConfig();`, but if I'm not wrong it's `OverlayState`depending on the version of angular, right ?

Comment: Yes. It is part of te latest version. It says available in other versions to, but with an other name.

Comment: I didn't manage to make it works on my project, could you edit the plunker I gave on the question, so I would have a complete example ?

Answer (score 3):

In case you cannot reproduce the failing version in plunkr, then some other css-styling in your project might be preventing the sticky-position.

In my case the sticky-position did not work in case the containing div had

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Maybe you have the value set on the containing div?

Comment: Yes, the containing div has overflow: hidden as style property.

Comment: But actually, I need this property, it helps me avoiding creating 2 scroll bars on the page (one for the page, one in the form). So I can't really stop using it.

Comment: can you set overflow hidden on the body? That would not interfere with sticky-position

Comment: Doesn't work, as you can see here https://plnkr.co/edit/6lHQNpyCwpFi3IyRDqpP?p=preview  the problem is that I can't see the end of the page with this trick :/

Answer (score 1):

Set a fixed height to the scrolling element and fix the button position:

```
<div style="height:calc(100vh - 100px) !important; overflow: scroll !important" class="mat-tab-body-content ng-trigger ng-trigger-translateTab">
```

......

```
<button style="top: calc(100vh - 50px) !important; position: fixed !important" md-button (click)='alert("clicked!");'>button</button>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PTW9TIrEYC0Lp27v00Vm?p=preview)

Comment: Okay, this might work for someone else, but it my case, creating a new scroll bar isn't possible. It's already in a page with a scroll bar, this would create 2 scroll bars and I want to avoid it.

Comment: Not a new one, it's the same but styled. Have you seen the demo? I could have added style in the css instead of inline styling

Comment: Well, in my project it doesn't work. I guess the plunker I provided doesn't represent exactly my project then. Thing is, in my project it creates a seconde scroll bar, and the buttons aren't fixed on the page, whatever scroll bar you use.

Comment: Remove overflow from the div and keep the height ?

Comment: It cuts the page before the end if I do as you said, so I can't see the end of the form :/ I updated my plunker (link in the question), maybe it'll help you.

Comment: See this demo please: https://plnkr.co/edit/APZ0qgo6iVFq8SNlWjXS?p=preview

Comment: Yes, but adding `overflow: scroll` to the form create another scroll bar in my page (on my app), since this form is integrated in another page. Also, it adds horizontal scroll bar, I don't know why (and don't want it). That aside I've always been told to avoid working with px, since this might not work on all kind of screens, don't know if it's true though.

Comment: The thing is, if the button is in the form, it cannot stay on place while the page is scrolling. It should either be outside the form either the form should get fixed height and overflow:auto/scroll. Also I avoid px in my projects, it was just for the example. I use either em either rem.

Comment: So, the "best" solution would be to put the button out of the form ? But then I'd have to edit my functions, that's what I wanted to avoid. Though if there's no other way, I guess I'll have to.

Comment: Let me think a little bit more :)

Comment: I guess the buttons are related to the form validation, etc... and it would be harder to move them out of the form than to leave them and try to arrange the remaining layout. I think there is nothing bad having two scrolls, the second appears on the bottom of the form when you still force the scrolling. The horizontal scroll can be take care of setting only vertical scroll, and with some calculation, the second vertical scroll could go away. Look at this plunker, please: https://plnkr.co/edit/OQrc8UAxIyPeNSSlpvWz?p=preview

Comment: Works fine, but as Robin Diijkhof posted a correct answer before you, I gave him the bounty. Thank a lot though, both of you did great job.